# how to change css transition start?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to rotate each of these 2 cards when I click on them, but it doesn't work properly.
I wanna the transition to occur only when I click on the card, not at the beginning.

And if there are any ways to enhance this code plz let me know, I'm still a beginner

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
/*body {
 background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
}*/

.box {
    width: 190px;
    height: 270px;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 310px;
    font-family: "Century Schoolbook", serif;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 255px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    transition: transform 0.7s linear;
    
}


ul { 
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center; 
       
}
.a {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000; 
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.b {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
.flip {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.rflip {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>S S</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <ul>
    <li class="box a" onclick="this.classList.toggle('rflip');">S</li>
   <li class="box b" onclick="this.classList.toggle('flip');">S</li>
  </ul>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it seems like its exactly behaving like you want it to do... ?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing as @J. Sadi. It doesn't rotate on load for me either.

Comment: Yeah it's rotating when I click it also

Comment: maybe here it doesn't, but when I run it on chrome I see this problem

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe look into different mouse events, such as 'mousedown' or 'mouseup'? and possibly add a small script to handle the callback.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>S S</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <ul>
    <li class="box a" onmouseup="flipCard($event, true)">S</li>
    <li class="box b" onmouseup="flipCard($event, false)">S</li>
  </ul>
  <script>
    function flipCard(event, goRight) {
       var classToToggle = goRight ? 'rflip' : 'flip';
       event.target.classList.toggle(classToToggle);
    }
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

If you want the transition to occur at a specific time, you can also use a timeout (1000 is milliseconds, so 1 second):

```
function flipCard(event, goRight) {
   setTimeout(function() {
      var classToToggle = goRight ? 'rflip' : 'flip';
      event.target.classList.toggle(classToToggle);
   }, 1000);
}
```

this was written without any testing, but the concept should be there

Answer (score 0):

From ur rflip class, I think u wish to have reverse flip thats why you have

```
transform: rotateY(180deg);
```

in a class 
If this is what you want to get rid of u can try

```
.a {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000; 
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
.rflip {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```